# $.each em um JSON de cidades

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach, each

Estou com um Json de cidades na seguinte estrutura:

```js
 var cidade = [
    {
      "sigla": "AC",
      "nome": "Acre",
      "cidades": [
        "Acrelândia",
        "Assis Brasil",
        "Brasiléia",
        "Bujari",
        "Capixaba",
        "Cruzeiro do Sul",
        "Epitaciolândia",
        "Feijó",
        "Jordão",
        "Mâncio Lima",
        "Manoel Urbano",
        "Marechal Thaumaturgo",
        "Plácido de Castro",
        "Porto Acre",
        "Porto Walter",
        "Rio Branco",
        "Rodrigues Alves",
        "Santa Rosa do Purus",
        "Sena Madureira",
        "Senador Guiomard",
        "Tarauacá",
        "Xapuri"
      ]
    },
    {
      "sigla": "AL",
      "nome": "Alagoas",
      "cidades": [
        "Água Branca",
        "Anadia",
        "Arapiraca",
        "Atalaia"....
```

Possui um select que no momento que o Estado é selecionado eu pego a sigla da seguinte forma:

```js
    $('#estado').change(function(){
        var estado = $(this).val();
         /*foreach inicia aqui

        })
    })
```

Estou  a tentar pegar todas a cidades e jogar dentro de um select pela sigla que fica armazenado na variavel estado, todavia não estou tendo sucesso...alguém teria um solução para este caso. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer como no exemplo abaixo, utilizando o método [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change-handler) e assim ir percorrendo os **`arrays`** de cidade que derem *match* com a opção do select de **estados**:

```js
let dados = [{
    "sigla": "AC",
    "nome": "Acre",
    "cidades": [
      "Acrelândia",
      "Assis Brasil",
      "Brasiléia",
      "Bujari",
      "Capixaba",
      "Cruzeiro do Sul",
      "Epitaciolândia",
      "Feijó",
      "Jordão",
      "Mâncio Lima",
      "Manoel Urbano",
      "Marechal Thaumaturgo",
      "Plácido de Castro",
      "Porto Acre",
      "Porto Walter",
      "Rio Branco",
      "Rodrigues Alves",
      "Santa Rosa do Purus",
      "Sena Madureira",
      "Senador Guiomard",
      "Tarauacá",
      "Xapuri"
    ]
  },
  {
    "sigla": "AL",
    "nome": "Alagoas",
    "cidades": [
      "Água Branca",
      "Anadia",
      "Arapiraca",
      "Atalaia"
    ]
  }
];

let cidades = $('#cidades');
let cidade;

$(() => {
  $('#estados').on('change', () => {
    var estado = $('#estados').val();              // pega o valor selecionado
    cidades.empty();                               // limpa o select de cidades
    mostraCidade(estado);                          // executa a função com estado de parâmetro
  })
})

function mostraCidade(estado) {
  for (let i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {         // percorre o array principal

    if (dados[i].sigla == estado) {                // pega o estado conforme a seleção
      cidades.show();                              // mostra o select de cidades escondido
      cidade = dados[i].cidades;                   // guarda as cidades respectivas
      for (let y = 0; y < cidade.length; y++)      // percorre as cidades respectivas
        cidades.append($('<option>', {             // cria as tags option
          text: cidade[y]                          // insere as cidades nos options
        }))
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="estados">
  <option selected disabled>Selecionar</option>
  <option value="AC">Acre</option>
  <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
</select>

<select id="cidades" hidden></select>
```

Comment: fiz apenas uma pequena adaptação para a minha realidade e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Legal man, sucesso aí!

Answer (score 1):

Desse jeito acho que resolve seu problema.

```
var cidade = [
{
  "sigla": "AC",
  "nome": "Acre",
  "cidades": [
    "Acrelândia",
    "Assis Brasil",
    "Brasiléia",
    "Bujari",
    "Capixaba",
    "Cruzeiro do Sul",
    "Epitaciolândia",
    "Feijó",
    "Jordão",
    "Mâncio Lima",
    "Manoel Urbano",
    "Marechal Thaumaturgo",
    "Plácido de Castro",
    "Porto Acre",
    "Porto Walter",
    "Rio Branco",
    "Rodrigues Alves",
    "Santa Rosa do Purus",
    "Sena Madureira",
    "Senador Guiomard",
    "Tarauacá",
    "Xapuri"
  ]
},
{
  "sigla": "AL",
  "nome": "Alagoas",
  "cidades": [
    "Água Branca",
    "Anadia",
    "Arapiraca",
    "Atalaia"
  ]
}
];
//Aqui pegue o estado conforme achar melhor
const estado = "AC";

const resultado = getCidades(cidade,estado);

console.log(resultado);

function getCidades(cidades,estado){
    let cidadesDoEstado=[];
    cidades.forEach(element => {
        if(element.sigla==estado){
            cidadesDoEstado = element.cidades;
        }
    });
    return cidadesDoEstado;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!